# Access 2010 Linked table to SharePoint 2007 missing column

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2010, sharepoint-2007

So I have created 2 Linked tables based on lists that exist on a SharePoint 2007 site ( `Institutions` & `Survey` ). The 2 lists are linked through a look up field in the `Survey` list that reference the `Name` field from `Institutions`.

After creating the `Survey` table in my Access 2010 database (.accdb) I notice that the lookup field that links the 2 lists together isn't present in the table. To make matters worse, there is another field ( `_EncodedAbsoluteURL` ) that I had deleted before but is present in the table, but this is only visible in `Design` view, in the `Datasheet` view it's nowhere to be found..

When I look at the table in `Design` view, I can even see a field called `Title1` that isn't shown in the `Datasheet` view nor can I find it on SharePoint, just like the field I mentioned before.

I have also tried to recreate this scenario with 2 simple lists that are connected in the same way but this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can see the column in the design view it means it has been imported just it is not visible in the datasheet view. That is because these columns are hidden in access. Access hides some columns by default.

You just have to right click on the header of any field and click on unhide. You get a list of all the fields from the SharePoint list. You want to show select the fields you want to display and close it.

Now you can see the columns. Hope this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the issue using the answer posted here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117707/access-linked-to-sharepoint-list-is-missing-fields/145501#145501?newreg=2c19852039b04d48b93539d39773044d

The problem was caused due to caching of data so if you clear your cache after deleting the table and then restart your DB the issue should be resolved.